# "Brg" at the end of emails

Tags: translation

A German colleague signs all his emails with "brg, [His Name]"  I can't find a direct translation of this.  Is it an expression, a general "from," A shortening of another phrase, or something else?

Comment: I never saw "brg" as an email signature. Could it be, that those are his initials?

Comment: Is that in English or German? There are German abbreviations like "mfg" (mit freundlichen Grüßen), but brg doesn't ring a bell.

Comment: @5pike I hadn't thought of that, but it's not his initials.  He signs: brg, [Name].  Added clarification.

Comment: Perhaps Best regards

Comment: Why don't you ask your colleague?

Comment: mfg... so freundlich können die Grüße nicht sein, wenn sich der Schreiber nicht mal die Zeit nimmt, die Grußformel auszuschreiben...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about brbs.

Comment: @Robert Oh, ich kenne Menschen die auch informell freundlich sein koennen ;)

Comment: My guess is that your colleague looked up a translation for _mfg_, and found that _brg_ resembled it the most

Comment: @Em1 I will be now, I suppose I was just worried it was something obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess it literally means "best regards". There's no matching German phrase I can think of (as a native German speaker) and I've seen quite a lot of strange abbreviations in emails over the years..

Comment: apparently confirmed by http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/BRG and http://www.acronymfinder.com/BRG.html

Comment: The more common abbreviation of "Best regards" is BR.